# Execute adb shell commands inside my android application

Tags: java, android, shell, adb

I need to apply certain adb command on boot of my device. But let's say I need it when I launch my app.

```
adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.navigation=*
```

I searched the web and came up with

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("settings put global policy_control immersive.navigation=*");
```

But unfortunally this comand doesn't work. If I plug my phone to PC and run adb command directly through the command window - everything is fine. But when I execute it from the app - nothing works and I even don't see any of related erroes in log.

I also tried this:
https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/03/android-executing-shell-commands.html
And comands like "ls /system/framework" work. But the one that I need - does not.

my device is redmi note 3 pro running miui 8 based on android 6.0.1. My project is in Eclipse.

Is it possible to perform such a taks without root or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("settings put global policy_control immersive.navigation=*");
```

try:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"settings", "put", "global", "policy_control", "immersive.navigation=*");
```

`exec` expects the command to be an array of strings where the first string is the command and the rest are its arguments

Comment: Just add `command.split(" ")`