# How enable proxy with authentification for all trafic how vpn?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, openvpn

In Xamarin android I try so commands

```
Process su = null;
su = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("settings put global http_proxy " + host+":"+port);
su.WaitFor();
su = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("settings put global global_http_proxy_host " + host);
su.WaitFor();
su = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("settings put global global_http_proxy_port " + port);
su.WaitFor();
su = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("settings put global global_http_proxy_username " + login);
su.WaitFor();
su = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("settings put global global_http_proxy_password " + password);
su.WaitFor();
```

but I see that those commands not change ip in application

I try find how connect proxy with authentification from open vpn with adb shell commands, but find nothing

Comment: I still don't understand what you said. Could you explain in detail what functions you want to achieve?

Comment: if I set for android app proxy - I see that in webview webrtc show real ip, not proxy ip, and for me need set proxy for all trafic from phone. in my code I try set global proxy, but its not working now

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930030/execute-adb-shell-commands-inside-my-android-application). It tells about adb shell commands. It passes an array of strings (each word being one element of the array) instead of one long string.

Considering that you use a mobile phone, you can see this: [Set network proxy on phone](https://hide-ip-proxy.com/configure-proxy-server-android/).

By the way,
[Docs for Java.Runtime.Exec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.lang.runtime.exec?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12) may be helpful to you.